# How to vertically center table cell in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table that contains a `form-inline` in a certain column. And this caused the contents in other columns not **vertically center aligned**. (As seen in the 1st code snippet) How to avoid this situation?

Actually, if I remove that `form-inline` from the table, everything works fine. (As seen in the 2nd code snippet) So I guess the problem comes from the `form-inline` embedded into the table.

```css
/* Fit the table cell width to the contents */

table th,
table td {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.center-screen {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-striped center-screen" style="max-width: 100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th style="width: 0.01%">Share</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>NVDA</td>
        <td style="width: 0.01%">1</td>
        <td>
          <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="TSLA" value="Sell">
              <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" max="100" style="width:70px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="TSLA" value="Buy">
              <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
/* Fit the table cell width to the contents */
table th,
table td {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.center-screen {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-striped center-screen" style="max-width: 100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th style="width: 0.01%">Share</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>NVDA</td>
        <td style="width: 0.01%">1</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there is a style by default, which prevents your table to be vertically in the middle.

Here it is:

```
.table td, .table th {
    padding: .75rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

so you can override this:
`vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: By adding `vertical-align: middle !important;` solve my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @hmhuang Good job!